# Ambiguity: "applications" tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

[applications](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/applications) could refer to [software apps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_software) or to formal requests for something (e.g. applying for a credit card, applying for a loan, etc.).

At the moment, there are only 23 questions tagged with [applications](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/applications).

We could create a "software-apps" tag, but I'm not sure if "software apps" is a common term.

Comment: Or perhaps just "software" instead of "software-apps".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[software](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software) is already an existing tag. I think this tag should be used for questions about software applications.

For questions about loan or credit card applications, I think the [applications](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/applications) tag is unnecessary. We already have tags for [loans](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/loans) and [credit-card](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/credit-card), and tags for specific types of loans such as [student-loan](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/student-loan) and [auto-loan](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/auto-loan). Those tags should be enough for these questions.

Let’s remove the [applications](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/applications) tag from all these questions and eliminate the tag altogether, replacing it with [software](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software) where appropriate.

Comment: For what it's worth I've been gradually implementing this answer (not all at once partly due to not having the time all at once and partly to not flood the front page).

Comment: @GS-ApologisetoMonica Thanks!

Comment: Aaaand it's gone!